# Stuck on startup page when flutter app reopens

Tags: android, flutter, app-startup

##### Preface: I am using `Flutter` to develop an `Android app`.But I found that when I open the App and then switch to the background, and then reopen the App after a while, the App will be `stuck on the startup page and cannot be opened normally`.

##### This is my `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
///There is Nothing.
}
```

##### This is my AndroidManifest.xml configuration：

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"  
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

##### The `launch_background` content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

##### And,the `main.dart` code:

```
void main() async {
  await onCreated();
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});
  
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: AppConfig.getAppName,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      locale: const Locale('zh', 'CN'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('zh', 'CN'),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
      ),
      defaultTransition: Transition.rightToLeft,
      getPages: AppRoutes.appRoutePages,
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.getAppInitPage,
      routingCallback: (value) {
        AppRoutes.onAppRouteCallback(value);
      },
      builder: FlutterSmartDialog.init(),
      navigatorObservers: [FlutterSmartDialog.observer],
      localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('zh', 'CN')
      ],
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

##### `onCreated()` content is:

```
 Future onCreated() async {
    logInfo("#startAppInit");
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await initMMKV();
    await _queryAppInfo();
    await CameraChecker.getInstance().startCheck();
    await _init();
    await _initAppEnv();
  }
```

## Through the following output log, you will find that the code "startAppInit" has no output.

##### Then, the output log in Logcat：

```
 I  SmartGc CheckAndAddTask : enable = 1 periodCheck = 0
 I  SmartGc CheckAndAddTask : enable = 1 periodCheck = 0
 D  Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10502; state: ENABLED
 I  setSystemFontMap SharedMemory
 I  setSystemFontMap Typaface
 I  applyConfigurationToResources: smallestScreenWidthDp = 443mMaxBounds = Rect(0, 0 - 1122, 2442)
 W  Unable to open '/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.dm': No such file or directory
 W  Unable to open '/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.dm': No such file or directory
 I  Init compatible state: true
 D  HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in.
 I  add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory.
 E  Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
 W  Unable to open '/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.sidecar.dm': No such file or directory
 W  Unable to open '/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.sidecar.dm': No such file or directory
 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~KjocvaBbLJ3H408L42y5SQ==/com.silence.flutter_demo-6AYuhVbD68Z84OIS_YyisQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~KjocvaBbLJ3H408L42y5SQ==/com.silence.flutter_demo-6AYuhVbD68Z84OIS_YyisQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 W  CUST VERSION = false, use class = class android.app.HwCustApplicationPackageManagerImpl
 V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.silence.flutter_demo' set to: 'default'
 V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.silence.flutter_demo: false
 I  apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.silence.flutter_demo#0#256
 V  Updatable production driver is not supported on the device.
 I  need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=0 newCnt=1
 I  SmartGc process: com.silence.flutter_demo enalbed: 1
 I  apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.silence.flutter_demo#0#0
 I  need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
 D  Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
 D  Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
 I  VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
 I  Installing application
 I  VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
 I  init processName:com.silence.flutter_demo pid=24330 uid=10502
 E  AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: AtomicFile[/data/user/0/com.silence.flutter_demo/files/hw_cached_resid.list]
 I  loadHwSystemFonts, isNightMode false, fontWeightScale is 100
 I  update not variable theme font
 I  finishPreloaded preloadStatus 0
 V  Handling launch of ActivityRecord{a1e9942 token=android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d {com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity}}
 D  disableOutlineDraw is true
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 E  isInSupportList 'com.silence.flutter_demo' is a game? no; or product supported? yes
 I  [GetTotalMemory] total memory =7471888KB
 I  [0020080c] pn: com.silence.flutter_demo, p: 24330
 I  HwCustType is 0
 E  open file error
 I  no cota live update cust policy found
 I  GetCfgDirRealPolicyValue: custPolicyDirs: /system/magic/base:/system/magic/china:/system/magic/oversea:/system/magic/china_honor:/system/magic/oversea_honor:/vendor/etc:/odm/cust/all/cn:/odm/etc:/odm/hn_odm/LGE-AN00:/product_h/etc:/product_h/region_comm/china:/preas/china:/product_h/hn_oem/LGE-AN00:/preload/LGE-AN00/all/cn:/cust/global:/cust/def/cn:/version/cust/all/cn:/version/special_cust/LGE-AN00/all/cn:/cust/cotalite:/cust/ecota
 I  [0030080c] no spt app: com.silence.flutter_demo
 V  callActivityOnCreate
 I  Found extracted resources res_timestamp-2-1701048852257
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 W  ApkAssets1 has N = 0
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1830:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeL' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1831:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeL' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1832:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeL' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1833:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeL' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1834:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeL' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1836:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeM' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1837:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeM' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1838:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeM' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1839:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeM' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1840:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeM' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1842:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeS' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1843:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeS' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1844:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeS' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1845:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeS' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1846:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeS' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1848:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeXs' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1849:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeXs' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1850:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeXs' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1851:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeXs' alias target not found
 D  [SkFontMgr Android Parser] /system/etc/fonts.xml:1852:4: warning: 'ChineseBigSizeXs' alias target not found
 W  type=1400 audit(0.0:213440): avc: denied { read } for name="max_map_count" dev="proc" ino=14176327 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c246,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_max_map_count:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.qualcomm.timeservice
 I  QUALCOMM build                   : 2e98867c23, Ibac4945cc0
    Build Date                       : 12/14/22
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.36.08.16
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
 I  Build Config                     : S P 12.1.1 AArch64
 I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
 I  Driver Version                   : 0615.57
 I  PFP: 0x01730155, ME: 0x00000000
 W  Could not find QSPM HAL service. Skipping adreno profile processing.
 D  Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=-2113788497 in 30000ms(Backend next call timestamp 0). Attempt 1
 D  Compat change id reported: 194532703; UID 10502; state: ENABLED
 D  Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=-2108807760 in 86400000ms(Backend next call timestamp 0). Attempt 1

 I  Considering local module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:10000 and remote module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:0
 I  Selected local version of com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode
 W  com.silence.flutter_demo requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
 W  The service for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.zap is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
 I  The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:42065/4_AJJF3o01A=/
 W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
 W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
 W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
 W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
 D  Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
 W  A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
 D  Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
 D  Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
 I   old windowMode:0 new windoMode:1
 D  Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
 I  add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{a1e9942 token=android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d {com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d
 I  set decor visibility 4
 I  scaleDisplayModeInRog, return new display mode = {id=1, width=1122, height=2442, fps=60.000004, alternativeRefreshRates=[]}
 I   old windowMode:1 new windoMode:1
 D  dispatchInputInterval 1000000
 W  Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.precompile_skshader_config"
 I  isSystemInDarkMode isResUiModeYes: false, isDarkMode: false
 I  set decor visibility 0
 W  type=1400 audit(0.0:213441): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_display_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=589 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c246,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_display_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.qualcomm.timeservice
 D  onViewRootImplSet activityToken android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d,activityClientRecord ActivityRecord{a1e9942 token=android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d {com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity}},isHnNavigationHide false isHidePrivateFlag = false
 D  onViewRootImplSet activityToken android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d,activityClientRecord ActivityRecord{a1e9942 token=android.os.BinderProxy@debb38d {com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity}},isHwNavigationHide false
 W  depended package hiTouch does n't exist!
 I  HiTouch restricted: system app HiTouch don't exist.
 D  onAttached, package=com.silence.flutter_demo, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=true
 I  184819560 attach
 I  184819560 win vis 0
 I  REFRESH_STATUS_BAR_ATTRS OnContentApplyWindowInsetsListener has SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701bf30
 I  [](id:5f0a00000000,api:0,p:-1,c:24330) connect: controlledByApp=false
 I  BLASTBufferQueue : comm:ycnet.pv_manage isTargetApp:0
 D  RCS is disable
 I  REFRESH_STATUS_BAR_ATTRS OnContentApplyWindowInsetsListener has SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS
 I  184819560 setWindowStopped false
 I  [VRI[MainActivity]#0(BLAST Consumer)0](id:5f0a00000000,api:0,p:-1,c:24330) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701c2a0
 E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701f210
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701f160
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701e0e0
 I  [](id:5f0a00000001,api:0,p:-1,c:24330) connect: controlledByApp=false
 I  184819560 create Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity])/@0xff75db9 Surface(name=Background for SurfaceView[com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity])/@0xf775fe Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity](BLAST))/@0xfc4d15f android.graphics.BLASTBufferQueue@d1247ac

 I  [SurfaceView[com.silence.flutter_demo/com.silence.flutter_demo.MainActivity]#1(BLAST Consumer)1](id:5f0a00000001,api:0,p:-1,c:24330) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae70003c0
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae701f370

 I  setAllowedHwForceDark:false package:com.silence.flutter_demo mCurrProcessState:0 mIsPackageNameChange:false hwForceDarkState:0 isViewAllowedForceDark:true isLastHonorForceDark:false
 I  AGPServiceClient ConnectLocked
 W  Expecting binder but got null!
 I  removeInvalidNode jank list is null
 I  init Rme, version is: v1.0
 I  init Rme, version is: v1.0
 I  current pid:24330 AppType:-1
 D  disableOutlineDraw is true
 I  init Rme, version is: v1.0
 I  current pid:24330 AppType:-1
 D  Compat change id reported: 193247900; UID 10502; state: ENABLED
 I  send MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED msg
 D  showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=true; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
 W  startInputReason = 1
 W  startInputReason = 6
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae7020c30
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae7020b80
 I  SurfaceControl 0x7ae7011ae0
 I  nativeRelease 0x7ae701f370 count: 2
 I  ~SurfaceControl 0x7ae701f370
 I  nativeRelease 0x7ae70003c0 count: 2
 I  ~SurfaceControl 0x7ae70003c0
 I  nativeRelease 0x7ae701dcc0 count: 5
 I  ~SurfaceControl 0x7ae701dcc0
 I  init lrucache size: 4194304 pid=24330
 V  printErrorResource, maybe not an error because module has entative action to load resource.
 D  Installing profile for com.silence.flutter_demo
 D  Making request to: https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3
 D  tagSocket(4) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 D  tagSocket(4) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 D  tagSocket(4) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 D  tagSocket(4) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 D  tagSocket(4) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

#### Hope teachers can help me,thanks.

How to resovle the question..

Comment: This issue only on emulator? if so try in a real device

Comment: Try flutter clean and then do the pub get. are you seeing any dependencies error?

Comment: I develop using real devices，and have tried several way which contains your suggest

Comment: My device is honor magic 4 ,android 12